# Format Excel / CSV file using VB6

Tags: excel, csv, vb6

I have a Raw data that will parse using `VB6` and get only the specific data, I already get the specific data. My problem now is this. I use `writeline` to write the specif data into another Excel/CSV file. My problem is this, I can already write the data in the CSV/ Excel file but it is written only in the first column so the tendency is all the data will write in the first column only. Can someone please help me, how can I make in per column? for example the first line that needed is in the first column and after that the second line is in the second column and so and so forth. Thank you in advance for the help :)

below is my code.

```
Dim i, ii, num As Long
Dim ff As Integer
Dim sText As String
Dim itmX As ListItem
Dim x, y As Integer
Dim ex As Excel.Application
Dim sheet As Excel.Workbook
Dim Csheet As Excel.Range
Dim wsheet As Excel.Worksheet, snum As Long

Dim strTransform() As String
Dim strTemp() As String
Dim intI As Integer
Dim intJ As Integer
Dim intMax As Integer
Dim p(29) As String
Dim adata() As String
Dim time1() As String
Dim holder1, holder2, holder3
Dim time2() As String
Dim lngIndex As Integer
Dim lngIndexx As Integer
Dim totaltime() As String

Dim myFSOww As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFSOr As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFSOw
Dim ft1 As TextStream
Dim ts, ts2, ts3, ft2, r, a, b, z, c, minus, time_num1, time_num2, time_num3, time_num4, comp
Dim date_num1, date_num2, d_t, total_parse, flow_total, req_flow, aia, air, cer, cla, clr, dsa
Dim dsr, dwa, dwr, ida, idr, noa, nor, pua, pur, rsa, rsr, ula, ulr
Set myFSOw = myFSOww.GetFile("C:\Users\user\Documents\bebe folder\Projects SSD\LTE Raw Data\Peek_data.csv")
Set myFSOr = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = myFSOr.GetFile(txtfilename.Text)
Set ft1 = ts.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault)
Set ft2 = myFSOw.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting)

Do Until ft1.AtEndOfStream
  On Error Resume Next
        a = ft1.ReadLine
        b = a
        p(0) = a
        r = r + 1
        Text1.Text = r
        z = Left(b, 1)

        If Not IsNumeric(z) Then
            adata = Split(a, ",")
            For i = 0 To UBound(adata)
                Text3 = adata(i)
                    If Text3 <> "Time Stamp" And txt_tag = Empty Then
                        ft2.WriteLine Text3

                    End If
            Next
        txt_tag = 1

        Else

        'FOR TIME
        p0 = "00:00"
        p1 = "01:00"
        p2 = "02:00"
        p3 = "03:00"
        p4 = "04:00"
        p5 = "05:00"
        p6 = "06:00"
        p7 = "07:00"
        p8 = "08:00"
        p9 = "09:00"
        p11 = "11:00"
        p12 = "12:00"
        p13 = "13:00"
        p14 = "14:00"
        p16 = "16:00"
        p17 = "17:00"
        p18 = "18:00"
        p19 = "19:00"
        p20 = "20:00"
        p21 = "21:00"
        p22 = "22:00"
        p23 = "23:00"

        h1 = "1:00"
        h2 = "2:00"
        h3 = "3:00"
        h4 = "4:00"
        h5 = "5:00"
        h6 = "6:00"
        h7 = "7:00"
        h8 = "8:00"
        h9 = "9:00"

        If holder1 = "" Then
            time1 = Split(a, ",")

            For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(time1)
                holder1 = time1(lngIndex)
                    If holder1 = time1(1) Then
                        txt_dt = holder1
                       If Len(txt_dt) = 19 Then
                           txt_t = Right(txt_dt, 8)
                           txt_d = Left(txt_dt, 10)
                           txt_t = Left(txt_t, 5)
                       ElseIf Len(txt_dt) = 14 Then
                           txt_t = Right(txt_dt, 4)
                           txt_d = Left(txt_dt, 10)
                       ElseIf Len(txt_dt) = 15 Then
                           txt_t = Right(txt_dt, 5)
                           txt_d = Left(txt_dt, 10)
                       End If

                        txt_trm = Trim(txt_t)
                        txt_t = txt_trm

                        If txt_t = p0 Or txt_t = p1 Or txt_t = p2 Or txt_t = p3 Or txt_t = p4 Or txt_t = p5 Or txt_t = p6 Or txt_t = p7 Or txt_t = p8 _
                            Or txt_t = p9 Or txt_t = p10 Or txt_t = p11 Or txt_t = p12 Or txt_t = p13 Or txt_t = p14 Or txt_t = p15 Or txt_t = p16 _
                            Or txt_t = p17 Or txt_t = p18 Or txt_t = p19 Or txt_t = p20 Or txt_t = p21 Or txt_t = p22 Or txt_t = p23 _
                            Or txt_t = h1 Or txt_t = h2 Or txt_t = h3 Or txt_t = h4 Or txt_t = h5 Or txt_t = h6 Or txt_t = h7 Or txt_t = h8 _
                            Or txt_t = h9 Then
                                holder1 = time1(lngIndex)
                        Else
                                holder1 = ""
                                GoTo 1
                        End If
                    End If

            Next lngIndex

        Else
            time2 = Split(a, ",")
            For lngIndexx = 0 To UBound(time2)
                holder2 = time2(lngIndexx)
                    If holder2 = time2(1) Then
                        txt_dt = holder2 'this is my time
                            If Len(txt_dt) = 19 Then
                                txt_t = Right(txt_dt, 8)
                                txt_d = Left(txt_dt, 10)
                                txt_t = Left(txt_t, 5)
                            ElseIf Len(txt_dt) = 14 Then
                                txt_t = Right(txt_dt, 4)
                                txt_d = Left(txt_dt, 10)
                            ElseIf Len(txt_dt) = 15 Then
                                txt_t = Right(txt_dt, 5)
                                txt_d = Left(txt_dt, 10)
                            End If
                        txt_trm = Trim(txt_t)
                        txt_t = txt_trm

                        If txt_t = p0 Or txt_t = p1 Or txt_t = p2 Or txt_t = p3 Or txt_t = p4 Or txt_t = p5 Or txt_t = p6 Or txt_t = p7 Or txt_t = p8 _
                            Or txt_t = p9 Or txt_t = p10 Or txt_t = p11 Or txt_t = p12 Or txt_t = p13 Or txt_t = p14 Or txt_t = p15 Or txt_t = p16 _
                            Or txt_t = p17 Or txt_t = p18 Or txt_t = p19 Or txt_t = p20 Or txt_t = p21 Or txt_t = p22 Or txt_t = p23 _
                            Or txt_t = h1 Or txt_t = h2 Or txt_t = h3 Or txt_t = h4 Or txt_t = h5 Or txt_t = h6 Or txt_t = h7 Or txt_t = h8 _
                            Or txt_t = h9 Then
                                holder2 = time2(lngIndexx)
                        Else
                                holder2 = ""
                                GoTo 1
                        End If

                    End If
             Next lngIndexx

        End If

    'subtract array time1 from time2
1

        If holder1 <> "" And holder2 <> "" Then
            For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(time2)
                holder3 = time2(lngIndex) - time1(lngIndex)
                If write1 = 0 And lngIndex = 1 Then
                    ft2.WriteLine time2(1)
                    write1 = 1
                ElseIf write1 = 1 And lngIndex <> 1 Then
                    ft2.WriteLine holder3
                End If

            Next
            ft2.WriteBlankLines 1
        End If
        write1 = 0
  End If
DoEvents

Loop
List1.AddItem Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS") & " Time end"
Set ft2 = Nothing
```

Comment: What are you writing: CSV format or Excel? There is an enormous difference. What is "writeline"? This is not a VB6 command. Finally, you *must* post some code if you want a correct answer. Just enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'd guess the FSO may be involved here.

Comment: Why use FSO? VB6 has its own file handeling

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw I am using `CSV`.. `WriteLine` is code of VB6 when you  use FSO in writing. I will edit my question.

Comment: @DenzilNewman because it is better than the own file handle of VB6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bebebe, its hard to answer your question without real context or example code.  How do you have this "RAW" data and what is the export format.
If you want to create a CSV you could use something like this - (demo based on array)

```
Dim ff As Long, strFilePath As String
Dim rLoop As Long, cLoop As Long
Dim strLine as String
ff = Freefile
strFilePath = App.Path
If Right$(strFilePath, 1)<>"\" Then strFilePath = strFilePath  & "\"

Open strFilePath&"demo.csv" For Output As ff

For rLoop = 0 To numRows -1 'Could use uBound or set a value if fixed - I dont know how you have this RAW DATA
  strLine = ""
  For cLoop = 0 To numCols -1 'Could use uBound if array
     If cLoop>0 Then strLine  = strLine & ","
     strLine = strLine & """" & rawDataArray(rLoop, cLoop) & """"
  Next cLoop
  Print #ff, strLine 
Next rLoop
Close #ff
```

If however you require an ACTUAL excel file, Id suggest creating an instance of Excel using COM - see the ms site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t9k08y5(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: thank you for the comment but is there other way that FSO should use